# Looping SQL Though R

Tags: sql, r

I have a table ("my_table") located on a SQL database server.

This table has 1000 rows - I am trying to select 100 rows of this table at a time (making sure that no row is selected twice and all rows are selected), and then append all these mini tables into a single table.

For example:

- result_1: rows 0 - 100
- result_2: rows 101-200
- etc.

I tried to do this with the falling code:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
sequence = seq(from = 1, to = 1000, by = 100)

the_list = list()

for (i in 1:10)
{

for (j in 1:sequence)

{

result_i = DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from my_table ORDER BY ID limit 100 OFFSET J;")

the_list[[i]] = result_i

}

}

final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, the_list)
```

I thought I could do this with a loop, but I don't think that SQL is recognizing my loop index.

Can someone show me how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: SQL code as you have here has no concept of variables in the calling environment. Look into [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) using either bound-parameters or `glue::glue_sql` for putting those into the query.

Comment: Wow! parametrized queries! thank you! I will look into this!

Comment: I think G.Grothendieck's answer of using `fetch`'s built-in partial download is by far the better solution: you don't need to alter your SQL code at all, you have no concerns about ordering or repeated data, and it's by-design and canonical for the package.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dbFetch` as shown.

```
library(RSQLite)

# Create test database in memory with one 6 row table.
m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, 'BOD', BOD)

res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from BOD")

# fetch 4 rows at a time    
L <- NULL; i <- 0
while(!dbHasCompleted(res)) {
  i <- i + 1
  L[[i]] <- dbFetch(res, n = 4)
}

dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(con)

library(dplyr)
Data <- bind_rows(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(data.table)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
sequence <- seq(from = 1, to = 1000, by = 100)
results_list <- lapply(sequence, function(x) {
  qstr <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET %s', x)
  res <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, qstr)
  res
}) 
results_df <- rbindlist(results_list) |> as.data.frame()
print(results_df)
```